# Difficulty using Resilience4j

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I'm trying to use resilience4j with springboot 3 in my application. but it doesn't arrive in the fallback method, can someone tell me what's wrong?

I tried to follow the official documentation, and I had no success,

Based on the code snippets, can anyone identify what is going wrong with the following code?

Application.properties

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: '\*'
management.endpoint.health.show-details: always

management.health.diskspace.enabled: false
management.health.circuitbreakers.enabled: true
management.health.ratelimiters.enabled: false

info:
name: ${spring.application.name}
description: ecommerce pedidoapi
environment: ${spring.profiles.active}
version: 0.0.1

management.metrics.tags.application: ${spring.application.name}
management.metrics.distribution.percentiles-histogram.http.server.requests: true
management.metrics.distribution.percentiles-histogram.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.calls: true

resilience4j.circuitbreaker:
instances:
pedidoapi:
registerHealthIndicator: true
slidingWindowSize: 10
minimumNumberOfCalls: 5
permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 3
automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled: true
waitDurationInOpenState: 5s
failureRateThreshold: 50
eventConsumerBufferSize: 10
```

Service.java

```
public static final String PEDIDOAPI = "pedidoapi";

    public UserModel returnUserDataFallback(Exception userExeception){  
        System.out.println("Fallback");
        return new UserModel( 1L, "user" ,"one", "111.111.111-23" , "2199999999", true, null, null);
    }
    
    
    @CircuitBreaker(name = PEDIDOAPI, fallbackMethod = "returnUserDataFallback")
    public UserModel getUser(Long idUsuario) {
        UserModel user = null;
        user =userFeignClient.getById(idUsuario).getBody(); 

        return user;
    }


public Optional<PedidoModel> registerPedido(@Valid PedidoModel pedidoModel) throws Exception {

        UserModel user = getUser(pedidoModel.getIdUsuario());
        ...
        return Optional.of(pedido);
    }
```

Controller.java

```
@PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<String> registerPedido(@Valid @RequestBody PedidoModel pedidoModel) throws Exception {

        return pedidoService.registerPedido(pedidoModel)
                .map(res -> ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("Pedido criado com sucesso"))
                .orElse(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build());

    }
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.blue</groupId>
    <artifactId>pedidoapi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>pedidoapi</name>
    <description>Api do pedido</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.14</version>            
        </dependency>
      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>resilience4j-reactor</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot3</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
            
        <!--<dependency>
          <groupId>io.vavr</groupId>
          <artifactId>vavr-jackson</artifactId>
          <version>0.10.3</version> 
        </dependency>   --> 
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>netflix-candidates</id>
            <name>Netflix Candidates</name>
            <url>https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: First based on the docs spring cloud 2022.0.2 requires Spring Boot version 3.0.5... https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: Did you read the documentation explaining the [consequence of Spring's proxy implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop/proxying.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies) is a method invoking another method on the same object won't be intercepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring AOP/Proxy is the reason for the fallback not being triggered. When annotated with `@CircuitBreaker` a proxy instance of the service class is created and used. The proxies work in such a way that calls from one bean/class to another bean/class are intercepted, and it cannot intercept calls from method to method **within the bean/class**.

Hence workaround would be to move the circuit breaker annotated method and fallback method to a different class.

Downstream.java

```
    public UserModel returnUserDataFallback(Exception userExeception){  
        System.out.println("Fallback");
        return new UserModel( 1L, "user" ,"one", "111.111.111-23" , "2199999999", true, null, null);
    }
    
    
    @CircuitBreaker(name = PEDIDOAPI, fallbackMethod = "returnUserDataFallback")
    public UserModel getUser(Long idUsuario) {
        UserModel user = null;
        user =userFeignClient.getById(idUsuario).getBody(); 

        return user;
    }
```

Also the fallback method would be triggered for any kind of Exception since it accepts `Exception` as an argument. `CallNotPermittedException` can be used which indicates the Circuit Breaker is in OPEN State.

Comment: I followed your suggestions and it worked here in my project, Thanks!